# scandir() returning only "Array"

Tags: php, scandir

I'm new with PHP so, I'm getting a problem.

I want to list files as well as directories from a specific directory `users`.

**I'm using this code:**

```
<?php
   $dir = "users/";
   $fl = scandir($dir);
   echo $fl;
?>
```

which is return only `Array`, even if the directory have files.

My PHP version is `5.3.5`

Comment: Try `print_r($f1)` instead of `echo $f1`.

Comment: `echo` is not for printing `array`s.

Comment: You should use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) like this way `print_r($fl);` OR [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for printing array/Dumps information about a variable not `echo`.

Comment: `print_r($fl)` worked for me. thnx. XD

Comment: You see `Array` because what is returned from `scandir()` is an array of filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do in this way..

```
<?php
   $dir = "users/";
   $fl = scandir($dir);
   foreach (scandir($dir) as $fl)
   echo $fl."<br>";
?>
```

Output like:

```
.
..
abc.txt
```